# Are These the Only 5 Fairy-Tale-Based Batman Villains?

Tags: dc, batman

I have recently been trying to catch up on as much Batman mythos as I can, however, I have only been able to get my hands on the first three Arkham games, the original Adam West Batman film, the first two Christopher Nolan films, the four Burton/Schumacher films, and the Season 1 box set for Gotham. That being said, I have noticed in the first two Arkham games the following fairy-tale-based villains:

1 **Cyrus Gold/Solomon Grundy** A zombie-like villain who took the name Solomon Grundy from a 19th century nursery rhyme of the same name.

2 & 3 **Dumfrey & Deever Tweed/Tweedledum & Tweedledee** Identical cousins who could pass as brothers, they resemble the characters Tweedledum & Tweedledee from Alice in Wonderland so much that they adopt the names, going on a crime spree.

4 **Jervis Tetch/The Mad Hatter** Obsessed with hats, developed a fixation on Alice in Wonderland and the characters in it, particularly the Mad Hatter and Alice.

5 **Humphry Dumpler/Humpty Dumpty** Man with an egg-shaped head and a compulsive need to fix things he considers 'broken'.

Intrigued by these five chapters, I was curious if there may have been any more, like maybe the Red Queen or Cheshire Cat from Alice in Wonderland, a character from an old fairy tale, or even a nursery inspired villain, much like Solomon Grundy & Humpty Dumpty.

I would appreciate any input.

Comment: What counts as a "Fairy Tale"? I'm not sure *Alice in Wonderland* meets most definitions of the phrase

Comment: One quibble: Grundy is a Green Lantern villain.

Comment: @Politank-Z Grundy fights Batman plenty of times.  I would venture to call him one of my favorite Batman villans despite the fact he originially fought the original (I think..yeah wood) Green Lantern.

Comment: Joker fights Superman plenty of times. Slade Wilson fights everybody at one time or another. I would still call them Batman and Teen Titans villains respectively. Grundy was not just an Alan Scott / Green Lantern villain, he was an, if not *the* arch nemesis. That said, it is a quibble and not an outright objection.

Answer (score 5):

### *Alice in Wonderland*/Lewis Carroll related villains:

[image]

- [Alice](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Alice)
- [White Rabbit](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/White_Rabbit)<sup>1</sup>
- [Lion](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/The_Lion)<sup>1</sup>
- [Carpenter](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/The_Carpenter)<sup>1</sup>
- [Walrus](http://www.comicvine.com/the-wonderland-gang/4060-57238/characters/)<sup>1</sup>
- [Unicorn](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/The_Lion)<sup>1</sup>
- [March Harriet](http://www.comicvine.com/the-wonderland-gang/4060-57238/characters) (a reference to the March Hare).<sup>1</sup>
- There is a villain named [Cheshire](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Cheshire), but she doesn't seem to have any connection to the Cheshire Cat.

[image]
*Walrus, Lion, Unicorn, March Harriet.*

### Other Fairytale/Children's Story related villains:

- [Scarecrow](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Scarecrow) (in one continuity, Scarecrow sings "Ding dong, the Witch is Dead", a clear reference to the Scarecrow in *Wizard of Oz*)
- [Mister Toad](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Mister_Toad), possibly a reference to *Wind In the Willows*.

---

<sup>1</sup>Along with the Mad Hatter, Tweedle Dum and Tweedle Dee, these villains make up the Wonderland Gang.  For whatever reason, Alice doesn't appear to be a member of the gang.

Comment: Pretty sure there's a [Mad Hatter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mad_Hatter_(comics)) too. I still remember his sidequest in Arkham City.

Comment: @Ixrec - Yeah, but he's one of the five mentioned in the question, so he doesn't count as someone else.